# How to retain and display the user selected value in multi-select dropdown when page is refreshed using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I have a multi-select dropdown in which option elements are added dynamically by the jQuery function. The user can select multiple options from the dropdown. When the page gets refreshed, all the user-selected values are lost, and the dropdown is reset to its default value. I want to retain as well as display the user-selected value after the page is refreshed so that the user does not need to select the value again.

Below is the HTML code of multi-select dropdown:

```
<div id="keyAcct2">
 <select class="form-control rich-selectize" id="multiLevelDropdown" name="multiLevelDropdown" placeholder="" multiple></select>
</div>
```

Below is the jQuery function to load options values in dropdown:

```
function LoadmultiLevelDropdown (KeyLevel2s){
 $('#multiLevelDropdown').empty();
 $('#multiLevelDropdown')[0].selectize.clearCache('option');
 $('#multiLevelDropdown')[0].selectize.clearOptions();
 var keyLevel2Ids = [];
 if (KeyLevel2s.length > 0){
  $.each(KeyLevel2s, function (index, item){
   if(keyLevel2Ids.indexOf(item.KeyAccountLevel2Id) === -1){
    $('#multiLevelDropdown')[0].selectize.addOption([{ text: $.trim(item.KeyAccountLevel2Desc),    value: item.KeyAccountLevel2Desc }]);
    keyLevel2Ids.push(item.KeyAccountLevel2Id);
   }
  });
 }
}
```

I am able to store the dropdown values selected by the user in an array called KA2Val after a page refresh. But when I tried to display/show the user-selected values (after page refresh) using the below code written at the end of the above function, nothing happened.

```
$('#multiLevelDropdown').val(KA2Val);
```

How should I display/show the values selected by the user after a page refresh? When page gets refreshed, the multi-level dropdown should be selected with values selected by user before refresh.

I will be more than happy to answer all your questions.

Thank you.

Comment: If the data is not sensitive, you can store it on `localStorage` upon select then `get` it from there on page load.

Comment: After page load, I already have a value in a variable which was selected by user before page load. But I'm unable to show that value in multi-select dropdown.